# read all the files and store in one file using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodes

I have 3 Json file in my ***project/Folder***

### file1.json

```
{
  "id":"01",
  "name":"abc",
  "subject":[
    "subject1":"Maths",
    "subject2":"Science"
  ]
}
```

### File2.json

```
{
  "id":"01",
  "name":"dummy",
  "Degree":[
    "Graduation":"BCom",
    "Post Graduation":"MBA"
  ]
}
```

### File3.json

```
{
  "id":"BA01",
  "Address":"India",
  "P Address":[
    "State":"MP",
    "City":"Satna"
  ]
}
```

I wrote a code where I can read my ***project/Folder*** so I can read all the data which is present inside the json file and want to append in my ***output.json***

```js
fs.readdir(
    path.join(process.cwd(), "project/Folder"),
    (err, fileNames) => {
      if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
      // Loop fileNames array
      fileNames.forEach((filename) => {
        // Read file content
        fs.readFile(
          path.join(
            process.cwd(),
            "project/Folder",
            `${filename}`
          ),
          (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
            // Log file content
            const output = JSON.parse(data);
            fs.appendFile(
              path.join(
                process.cwd(),
                "project/Folder",
                `output.json`
              ),
              `[${JSON.stringify(output)},]`,
              (err) => {
                if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
              }
            );
          }
        );
      });
    }
  );
```

my expected output is like this as I want to append the data which I got from file1, file2, file3 json in output.json

```
[
   {
      file1.json data
   },
   {
      file2.json data
   },
   {
      file3.json data
   }
]
```

but in reality I am getting this as an output

```
[
  {
    file1.josn data
  },
]
[
  {
    file2.josn data
  },
]
[
  {
    file3.josn data
  },
]
```

I don't know how can I achieve my expected output like this even I wrote code properly but I think I am missing something, but I don't know what can someone help me to achieve my expected code?

```
[
   {
      file1.json data
   },
   {
      file2.json data
   },
   {
      file3.json data
   }
]
```

Comment: Is this for your personal daily use in your local machine or is this a code for an app? If it's for your specific personal use, there's an easy alternative with only few lines of bash script.

Comment: You can't directly append to a JSON file without hacking a bunch on partial parsing of the end of the file and then selective overwrites (not recommended).  If you want to append, then use a CSV formatted file as it is line-based and you can directly append lines to the file just fine.  To properly add to the JSON, you have to read it all into memory, parse it into the array, add an item to the array and then recovert it to JSON and write the whole file back to disk.  JSON does not lend itself to direct modification on disk.

Comment: this is for an app @MImamPratama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr = [];

fs.readdir(path.join(process.cwd(), "project/Folder"), (err, fileNames) => {
  if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
  // Loop fileNames array
  fileNames.forEach((filename) => {
    // Read file content
    fs.readFile(
      path.join(process.cwd(), "project/Folder", `${filename}`),
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
        // Log file content
        const output = JSON.parse(data);
        arr.push(output);
        fs.writeFileSync(
          path.join(process.cwd(), "project/Folder", `output.json`),
          JSON.stringify(arr),
          (err) => {
            if (err) throw console.log(err.message);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  });
});
```

maybe like this, push it to an array and then save it to a new file

Comment: I am getting same as my previous output

Comment: sry, try now, ive updated the code from fs.writeFile to fs.writeFileSync

Comment: thank you, Its working perfect now :D

Comment: you are welcome! 
maybe its better to update this part path.join(process.cwd(), "project/Folder", `output.json`), to `../output.json` so its in different folder.

the way you have it now if you run code multiple times it will read all json files including output.json and try to write from all 4 files to output.json so you will get messed up results

Comment: sure i will do it right away, thank you for the point :D

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't understand all of it. But this line (the second argument of `fs.appendFile`):

```js
`[${JSON.stringify(output)},]`,
```

If you change it to

```
`${JSON.stringify(output)},`,
```

Will make the result look like this:

```
{
   file1.json data
},
{
   file2.json data
},
{
   file3.json data
}
```

Then you can wrap them with brackets `[]`.